# How can I parse a string of text messages into an object

Tags: javascript, parsing

I want to parse text messages contained in a template string to the following JS object. Every text message is seperated by a new line and after the authors name there is a colon. The content of the message can also include new lines, square brackets and colons. What is your preferred way of solving this?

```js
let string = `[03.12.21, 16:12:52] John Doe: Two questions:
How are you? And is lunch at 7 fine?
[03.12.21, 16:14:30] Jane Doe: Im fine. 7 sounds good.`;

let data = {
  "03.12.21, 16:12:52": {
    "author": "John Doe",
    "content": "Two questions:\nHow are you? And is lunch at 7 fine?"
  },
  "03.12.21, 16:14:30": {
    "author": "John Doe",
    "content": "Im fine. 7 sounds good."
  },
}; // will be parseString()

function parseString() {
  // ?
}
```

Comment: No such thing as a JSON object, you mean a JavaScript object, or just object given the context of the question.

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: I havn't gotten anything to work yet.

Comment: Assuming the Characters `[ ] :` appear no where else in the message then you can try to do this using Regex

Comment: You Need To Split the String Using The Regex Using `.split()` function and then use `.push()` to add it into the JS Object

Comment: [] and : can appear in the text messages content. Also newlines can be in there, which would normally seperate the individual messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

```js
let string = `[03.12.21, 16:12:52] John Doe: Two questions:
How are you? And is lunch at 7 fine?
[03.12.21, 16:14:30] Jane Doe: Im fine. 7 sounds good.`;

let chunks = string.split(/^\[(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d, \d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d)\](.*?):/m);

let data = {};
for (let i = 3; i < chunks.length; i += 3) {
  const date = chunks[i - 2];
  const author = chunks[i - 1].trim();
  const content = chunks[i].trim();
  data[date] = {
    author,
    content,
  };
}

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: This works great for me. Thank you! I would like to understand your solution. What's the best way to go about that?

Comment: I was recommended this website, which breaks the regex function down. https://regex101.com/r/iCS96i/1

Answer (score 0):

I would split the to whole string into little pieces like: let string = date + author + content. With that its much simpler. Or use something like `string.split()`

Comment: How would you implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function parseMessage(message) {
   var messageObj = {};
   var messageArray = message.split(" ");
   messageObj.command = messageArray[0];
   messageObj.args = messageArray.slice(1);
   return messageObj;
}
```